# Можно ли при помощи js сделать запись в xml файл и создать на основе этого бд

Tags: javascript, xml

1. Можно ли при помощи чистого js сделать запись в xml файл? Если да, то как это сделать?
2. Возможно ли создать на основе этого бд? Поступила такая задача, но не представляю как это реализовать

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: Файловая система клиента - нет.  Внутренее хранилище браузера клиента (анонимное) - да. XML на серваке - да. Модификация на внутреннем хранилище - да. Модификация xml на сервере - с разрешения сервера. Взять xml файл клиента через диалог открытия файла или Drag&Drop и обработать на клиентской странице в браузере - да. Сохранить xml клиенту с помощью инструмента скачивания файлов в браузере - да. Остаётся определиться откуда вы хотите брать xml и куда хотите его девать.

Comment: nick_n_a,  1.) допустим через форму я хочу записывать данные в xml файл, и на другой странице изымать их, и использовать там. 2.) использовать данные для изменения в карусели. Но при этом на чистом js, без php. Да, такое извращение(а может и нет) сказала сделать преподавательница.